# How to send Digitalocean outbound traffic over floating ip from a python script?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, firewall, droplet

First of all thanks for the help, I'm trying to fix this problem for days

I know that is possible to route outbound traffic from a DigitalOcean droplet through its floating IP (a publicly-accessible static IP address that you can assign to a Droplet).

So, my droplet have 2 ip (regular and a floating ip)
As suggested in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/send-outbound-traffic-over-floating-ip, I found my droplet's "anchor IP" with

```
ip addr show eth0
```

I would like to make requests with python, using my IP as a proxy. I can do this? For example, something as:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:YY',
    'https': 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:YY',
}

# Create the session and set the proxies.
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

# Make the HTTP request through the session.
r = s.get('https://www....')
```

XX.XX.XX.XX is my anchor ip

YY -> What port I have to use?

I have to add some rules to my Firewall (UFW) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proxy feature of requests is for use with HTTP proxy servers. If you want traffic to be routed through a specific interface on the machine, you should use the routing feature in the OS (e.g. `route` in Linux).

Answer (score 5):

First, Assign a floating IP on your Droplet.

1. Install squid

   `apt-get update apt-get install -y squid`
2. Configure squid proxy: search on Google how to do basic configuration.
3. Find your droplet's "anchor IP" with

   `ip addr show eth0`

This is an example of output:

```
inet "YOUR_IP1"/20 brd 123.456.789.012 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet "YOUR_IP2"/16 brd 12.34.567.890 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

4. Now, your droplet have 2 ip: **YOUR_IP1** and **YOUR_IP2**.

Add these lines to /etc/squid/squid.conf:

```
acl myip_1 myip YOUR_IP1
tcp_outgoing_address YOUR_IP1 myip_1

acl myip_2 myip 10.17.0.5
tcp_outgoing_address 10.17.0.5 myip_2
```

and

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://PUBLIC_IP:PORT',
    'https': 'http://PUBLIC_IP:PORT', 
}

# Create the session and set the proxies. 
s = requests.Session() 
s.proxies = proxies

# Make the HTTP request through the session. 
r = s.get('https://www....')
```